# ImageIO write only load half the picture (socket)

Tags: java, sockets, javax.imageio, bytebuffer, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm trying to send an image from client to server using socket. I am able to send the image to server directory, but the image sent is not full.
What should I change?

Client code :

```
Part filePart = request.getPart("file"); 
InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();        

Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",51519);
OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
try {                       
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileContent);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", byteArrayOutputStream);

    byte[] size = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(byteArrayOutputStream.size()).array();

    outputStream.write(size);
    outputStream.write(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray());                   
}
catch (SocketException ex){
    BLL_Common.write_log(ex.toString(), "");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    BLL_Common.write_log(ex.toString(), "");
} finally {
    outputStream.flush();     
}
```

Server code :

```
String dir = "web/Admin/img/";     
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(51519);

while(true) {
 try {
  Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

  InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

  byte[] sizeAr = new byte[4];
  inputStream.read(sizeAr);
  int size = ByteBuffer.wrap(sizeAr).asIntBuffer().get();
  byte[] imageAr = new byte[size];

  inputStream.read(imageAr);
  BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageAr));                 

  String fileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

  ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(dir + fileName + ".png"));
 } 
 catch (SocketException ex) {
  //...
 } catch (IOException ex) {
  //...
 } 
}
```

This is the image loaded :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming that `read()` fills the buffer. You need `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Have a look at `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` while you're at it.

Of course you could just use `ImageIO.read()` directly on the socket input stream and avoid all this, and similarly `ImageIO.write()` directly to the socket output stream. But unless the original image isn't a JPEG you should just be copying bytes, without using `ImageIO` or `BufferedImage` at all.